# Connect point to closest feature in ArcGIS 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I have some points and some features. These points fall outside the features. I want to connect each point with a line to the closest feature. How can this be done using ArcGIS 10.2?

I have checked around toolbox but didn't manage to find the right tool for it.

Comment: So you want to draw a line from your point feature to the closest other feature?

Comment: Correct! Exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of the license level you have, but if you have an advanced license, you can run the [Generate Near Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001n000000) tool and feed the resulting table into the [XY to Line](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000tv000000) tool to get the desired output.

Comment: Hey Kevin, thanks a lot for your prompt reply!                 I can use the Generate Near Table tool. But when I use it and open the table I only get the feature's ID, the distance, and the near xy coordinates of the closest point of the feature. So the xy coordinates of the point that I want to connect are missing from the table, so I can later use properly the XY to Line. Point 1 to connect to closest point of Feature 1. Many thanks!

Comment: Sorry should have specified that you'll need to check the **Location** parameter in the Generate Near Table tool dialog. The result will then include both the from XY as well as the near XY.

Comment: I have checked the location but this "Specifies whether x- and y-coordinates of the nearest location of the near feature will be written to new fields NEAR_X and NEAR_Y, respectively"          So the xy coordinates of the point do not appear in this table, rather than nearest xy coordinates of the feature.

Comment: are you sure you're using version 10.2+ and not 10.1? It appears that the FROM_X, FROM_Y are included with the NEAR_X and NEAR_Y starting in 10.2. The quotation you mentioned is from the doc for 10.1 I believe. The 10.2 doc reads "Specifies whether x- and y-coordinates of the input feature's location and nearest location of the near feature will be written to the FROM_X, FROM_Y, NEAR_X, and NEAR_Y fields."

Comment: If you haven't got the input XY then add the fields to the table, run AddXY (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000032000000) join to the input using input_fid and then calculate the fields across the join.

Comment: many thanks to both of you guys. I have the 10.2 but FROM X, FROM Y do not appear in the attribute table. I tried the join solution and despite more time consuming, I 've got the required result. As soon as I have enough reputation, I will vote up both your answers. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

I've made a python script for that. Basicaly, we found the nearest point from all the points on our line feature. We group the created point by pair, then we create a line with those pairs. The last line add the created line to our initial line feature.

```
import arcpy 

fcpoint = r'mypoint'
fcline =  r'myline'
database = r'mydatabase'

# Set the workspace 
arcpy.env.workspace = database
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# find features only within search radius (no limit here)
search_radius = "" 
# find location nearest features
location = "LOCATION"
# avoid getting angle of neares features
angle = "NO_ANGLE"

# execute the function
arcpy.Near_analysis(fcpoint,fcline, search_radius, location, angle)

layer = arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(fcpoint,'NEAR_X','NEAR_Y','point_on_line_temp','2056') #don't forget to precise your own SRID
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(layer, database, 'point_on_line')
arcpy.Append_management (fcpoint, 'point_on_line', 'NO_TEST') 
arcpy.PointsToLine_management('point_on_line', 'line_from_point', "UNIQUE_ID_OF_MY_POINT", "", "NO_CLOSE") # Don't forget to give the unique ID of your point feature.
arcpy.AddField_management('line_from_point', 'CONNECTOR', 'FLOAT')
arcpy.AddField_management(fcline, 'CONNECTOR', 'FLOAT')

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor('line_from_point', 'CONNECTOR') as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = 1
        cursor.updateRow(row)
del cursor

# Remove this line if you want the connected line as separated feature, this line merge the created line with fcline 
arcpy.Append_management('line_from_point',fcline, 'NO_TEST')
```