# Generating Multiple Lines from point feature to closest point features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, line, xy

I am doing a transportation analysis on buildings in ArcGIS 10.2.

I need to find nearest point features to multiple feature classes and then generate lines to those closest point features.

I was reading another question post here about using the "generate near table" and "XY to line" tools to do this.  It worked fairly well, but I could not specify the tools to find and generate lines to each of the nearest features in multiple shapefiles/feature datasets.

ex: I have a point file for one building I need to generate a line to the closest bus stop, to the closest drinking fountain, to the closest bicycle lock rack.

There is a seperate dataset for each transportation feature (bike rack, water fountain, bus stop, etc...)

Can anybody help?

Here is the link to a similar problem:

[Connect point to closest feature in ArcGIS 10.2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103722/connect-point-to-closest-feature-in-arcgis-10-2)

Comment: Hi @Erick and welcome to GIS Stack Exchange. Have you tried [Batch mode](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00210000000w000000), which will allow you to run the same tool multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest either [Batch mode](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00210000000w000000) or, if it is possible, pre-merge the multiple targets using `Merge` geoprocessing tool into one.

Comment: Would I merge the targets after generating the near table?

Merging the .dbf

Comment: I'd use Batch mode to generate multiple near tables, then merge these tables into one table using `Merge` and, finally, convert them using `XY to Line` to a line feature class.